# How can I add 3 values to a larger list cyclically

Tags: python, list

What I want to do is take a smaller list with three values in it Ex. [97, 98, 99] and add it to a much larger list (1455 values long) by going through this larger list and adding the values one by one. The first value in the smaller list into the first value in the larger list and the first value in the smaller list to the third in the larger list etc.

Comment: Like this? 

`list1 = [97, 98, 99], list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]` becomes `list2 = [1, 97, 2, 98, 3, 99, 4, 5, ...]` ?

Comment: `i % 3` (or more generally, `i % len(smallerList)` will turn an index from the larger list into the corresponding cyclic index into the smaller list.

Comment: It would be more like this (I changed the original list so that it can be seen a little easier list1 = [97, 101, 117], list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...] becomes list2 = [98, 103, 120, 101, 106, 123,  104, 109, 126]

Comment: `l1 = [97, 101, 78]
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
l3 = []
for i in range(len(l2)//len(l1)):
    t = [i1 +i2 for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2[len(l1)*i:(i+1)*len(l1)])]
    l3.extend(t)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```py
[x + list1[i % len(list1)] for i, x in enumerate(list2)]
```

We're looping through list2 and taking those values straight from the list. By using the % operator and the length of list1, we cycle through list1 and go back to the first value once we've reached the end of list1.

Answer (score 0):

this type of problem as I get from the author, is could a sliding window addition

```
l1 = [97, 101, 78] # this is the sliding window
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # this is the array we want to add it to
l3 = [] # here where we will put the result 
# len(l2)//len(l1) number of steps to take how many len(l1) are in l2, in this case we want to use a sliding of len(l1) each time
for i in range(len(l2)//len(l1)): 
    # len(l1)*i:(i+1)*len(l1)]) get the next part of l2 by len(l1)
    t = [i1 +i2 for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2[len(l1)*i:(i+1)*len(l1)])]
    l3.extend(t) # add them to l3
print(l3)
# [98, 103, 81, 101, 106, 84, 104, 109, 87]
```